# Date in playframework 2.0-java is giving invalid value in form

Tags: java, forms, date, playframework-2.0

I have a form where I define:

```
@Required
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date mDate;
```

Now my in template I have:

```
@helper.inputDate(
                myForm("mDate")
        )
```

But when I submit the form I get an error as invalid value.

Comment: There is no stacktrace, it is just that the validation is not passed. I need to ask that if i have @Formats.DateTime(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy") on a java.sql.Date; what will be the format of the date? as 22/10/2012 dont work.

Answer (score 5):

This is really late, but hopefully it will be helpful to people who stumble upon this question.

If you go into chrome dev tools or firebug you'll see something like this when the error message is displayed:

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="start" value="2013-12-31">
```

That means the format sent back to the server is yyyy-MM-dd instead of dd/MM/yyyy.

Change the model field decorator to this:

```
@Required
@Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public Date mDate;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check type of mDate field. It must be `java.util.Date`, not `java.sql.Date`.